# How do I get my dropdown back?

Tags: unity, icons, gtk

Recently, I mucked around with KDE and got a (mostly) seamless uninstall once I decided that it wouldn't work for reasons.

However, this has led to a number of strange icon glitches appearing in a few places:

[image]

The dropdown arrow (or whatever was there) is now gone, and is nowhere to be found. Switching from and then back to `ubuntu-mono-dark` as a theme does not seem to help.

Is there anything I can do to restore this icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused by the `adwaita-icon-theme` package getting overwritten or otherwise altered.

Installing the latest version (as of the time of writing, `3.18.0-2ubuntu3.1` for Xenial) by running the below command may solve the problem:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall adwaita-icon-theme=3.18.0-2ubuntu3.1
```